# Vuetify : Tooltip doesn't work with custom Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

My tooltip doesn't work with my Custom Component. I wrap a Dialog in a Component and I want to add a tooltip.

My Vue.js version is `2.5.17` and Vuetify `2.1.15`

Componant A :

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
   <template v-slot:activator="{ on }" v-slot:item={item}>
      <ComponentB v-on="on">
      </ComponentB>
   </template>
   <span>Hello world!</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Component B:

```
<template>
   <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="800px">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
         <v-icon small v-on="on">
            add_comment
         </v-icon>
      </template>
      <v-card>
         <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">Title</span>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn icon @click="dialog = false">
               <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
         </v-card-title>
         <v-card-text class="pb-0">
            Hello world!
         </v-card-text>
         <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
            color="primary"
            text
            @click="dialog = false"
          >
            I accept
          </v-btn>
         </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
   </v-dialog>
</template>
```

I am beginner in VueJs, so may someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just move the tooltip into the child component, since it is technically part of the child component anyway. I did the best I could with the example code below, given the limited amount of code you provided in your question. Hopefully this helps!

```html
<!-- Component A (Parent) -->
<template>
   <ComponentB :item="item" />
</template>

<!-- Component B (Child) -->
<template>
   <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="800px">
      <v-tooltip bottom>
         <template v-slot:activator="{ on }" v-slot:item="item">
            <v-icon small v-on="on">
               add_comment
            </v-icon>
         </template>
         <span>Hello world!</span>
      </v-tooltip>
      <v-card>
         <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">Title</span>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn icon @click="dialog = false">
               <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
         </v-card-title>
         <v-card-text class="pb-0">
            Hello world!
         </v-card-text>
         <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
            color="primary"
            text
            @click="dialog = false"
          >
            I accept
          </v-btn>
         </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
   </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      item: {
        type: Object,
        default() {
          return {};
        }
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```